# SignUp and SignIn user using facebook

Tags: security, social-connected

Need to sign up user using Facebook account without using Social Connector.
I've created UserMembership with random password. But now how to signin this user? I mean complete `AuthenticationManager.Login(userName, password)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `Sitecore.Security.Authentication.AuthenticationManager.Login` function has an overload that just accepts the `username` as a string. You don't need to add in the password to authenticate the user. So once you have got back from Facebook that the user is authenticated, you could use that overload to log the user into Sitecore.